# Degraded server, how to solve this

Tags: php, systemd

I'm new to Ubuntu and just getting started understanding the principles.

My server shows after `systemctl status` the server state degraded.

I found the command `systemclt --failed` and it showed me the following:

```
UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● plesk-php54-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 5.4.45 FastCGI >Proce
● plesk-php55-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 5.5.38 FastCGI >Proce
● plesk-php70-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 7.0.21 FastCGI >Proce
plesk-php71-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 7.1.7 FastCGI Proces
● systemd-sysctl.service       loaded failed failed Apply Kernel Variables
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service loaded failed failed Create Static Device >N

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

6 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
lines 1-14/14 (END)...skipping...
> UNIT                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● plesk-php54-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 5.4.45 FastCGI >Proce
● plesk-php55-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 5.5.38 FastCGI >Proce
● plesk-php70-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 7.0.21 FastCGI >Proce
● plesk-php71-fpm.service      loaded failed failed The PHP 7.1.7 FastCGI >Proces
● systemd-sysctl.service       loaded failed failed Apply Kernel Variables
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service loaded failed failed Create Static Device >Nodes i

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

6 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Now the php versions it is trying to load aren't used by me.
But the to systemctl commands i'm not sure if they happen to influence the performance.

If anybody has suggestion i willl be grateful.

I tried using the search function and google, but didn't find something fitting. But it's also possible i didn't know what helps.

If the quotes are done wrong, i'm sorry, firсt time using this.